# Visual Studio, C# detailed chart

Tags: c#, sql, charts

I am creating small program what shows us total sell sum by months via chart, but my chart is not detailed enough, it shows for example what sum in 2012'07 was something between 20 and 40, but i need exact value. (32,4)

[image]

Help needed.

Code

```
 private void formGraph()
    {
        string database, host, user, pass, sqlParams, sqlQuery;
        string resultPassword = String.Empty;

        database = "";
        host = "localhost";
        user = "";
        pass = "";

        sqlParams = "Database=" + database + ";Data Source=" + host + ";User Id=" + user + ";Password=" + pass;
        sqlQuery = "SELECT YEAR(`importdate`) as 'Year', MONTH(`importdate`) as 'Month', SUM(`price`) as 'Sum' FROM `data` GROUP BY MONTH(`importdate`), YEAR(`importdate`) ORDER BY YEAR(`importdate`), MONTH(`importdate`) ASC LIMIT 12";

        MySqlConnection sqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(sqlParams);
        MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);

        try
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            MySqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (sqlReader.HasRows)
            {
                while (sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    string Sum = sqlReader["Sum"].ToString();
                    if (Sum.Contains(",")) Sum = Sum.Replace(",", ".");
                    if (Sum == "0") Sum = "1";
                    chart1.Series.Add(sqlReader["Year"].ToString() + '\'' + sqlReader["Month"].ToString());
                    chart1.Series[sqlReader["Year"].ToString() + '\'' + sqlReader["Month"].ToString()].Points.AddY(Sum);
                    //sqlReader["Year"].ToString() + '"' + sqlReader["Month"].ToString()
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException sqlError)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you expect us to help you without code?

Comment: I thought it is something like an options in Visual Studio :)

Comment: well, I dont think so. Seems like a code thing to me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go through all the series you have and set the `IsValueShownAsLabel`property to true. Like this, to do the very first one:

```
Chart1.Series[0].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 3):

```
Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10.0F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic)
```

*If you replace Series1.Name with yours it should work = display value on top of the column*

```
Chart1.Series(Series1.Name).IsValueShownAsLabel = True;
```